# MySQL lite django multitables

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7

I am working on a project from school and one of the questions is List all leagues with a (current) player named "Sophia".   I have been able to get all the leagues period, and all the players name Sophia. How ever I cannot seem to figure out how to start in the last table where the first name is reference the first table where the leagues are to get the answer I need. I am hoping someone can see what I am having issues seeing.  I have linked the models and views below.

```
Manage.py

from django.db import models

class League(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sport = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Team(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    league = models.ForeignKey(League, related_name="teams")

class Player(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    curr_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="curr_players")
    all_teams = models.ManyToManyField(Team, related_name="all_players")


views.py 

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import League, Team, Player

from . import team_maker

def index(request):
    context = {
        "leagues": League.objects.all(),
        "teams": Team.objects.all(),
        "players": Player.objects.all(),
        "baseball" : League.objects.filter(sport__contains="Baseball"),
        "women" : League.objects.filter(name__contains="Womens'"),
        "ice" : League.objects.filter(sport__contains="ice"),
        "nofootball" : League.objects.exclude(sport__contains="football"),
        "conferences" : League.objects.filter(name__contains="conference"),
        "atlantic": League.objects.filter(name__contains="Atlantic"),
        "teamdallas": Team.objects.filter(location__contains="Dallas"),
        "raptor": Team.objects.filter(team_name__contains="Raptor"),
        "cityloc": Team.objects.filter(location__contains="city"),
        "startT": Team.objects.filter(team_name__startswith="T"),
        "abc": Team.objects.order_by('location'),
        "cba": Team.objects.order_by('location').reverse(),
        "cooper": Player.objects.filter(last_name="Cooper"),
        "joshua": Player.objects.filter(first_name="Joshua"),
        "nocooper": Player.objects.filter(last_name="Cooper").exclude(first_name="Joshua"),
        "wyatt": Player.objects.filter(first_name="Alexander")|Player.objects.filter(first_name="Wyatt"),
        "atlanticsoccer" : Team.objects.filter(league__name__contains='atlantic', league__sport__contains="soccer"),
        "bostonp" : Player.objects.filter(curr_team__team_name__contains='Penguins'),
        "icbc" : Player.objects.filter(curr_team__league__name__contains='International Collegiate Baseball '),
        "footballlopez" : Player.objects.filter(curr_team__league__name__contains="American Conference of Amateur Football", last_name__contains="lopez"),
        "footballplayer" : Player.objects.filter(curr_team__league__sport__contains="football"),
        "sophia" : Team.objects.filter(curr_players__first_name__contains='sophia'),
        "sophiale" : Team.objects.filter(league__contains='sophia'),

    }

        print Team.objects.filter(league__contains='sophia')
        return render(request, "leagues/index.html", context)

def make_data(request):
    team_maker.gen_leagues(10)
    team_maker.gen_teams(50)
    team_maker.gen_players(200)

    return redirect("index")

index.html  just the part you need

<h5>Question 8</h5>
        {% for player in sophiale %}
        <li>{{player.name}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ol>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
League.objects.filter(teams__ all_players__first_name__contains='sophia')
```

Comment: The code doesnt break but <h5>Question 8</h5>
  {% for player in sophiale %}
     <li>{{League.name}}</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ol>    this should pull the leage names with sophie in them but it doesnt

Comment: Is there any data in your ManyToMany table maybe named 'xxx_player_all_teams'?